# How can I apply the following steps to my class?

Tags: python, function, class

So I'm trying to create a program that resembles an auction, and so far I have created a class that takes in information about the person who is bidding, the bidder id, and the code (in that order in `def(__init__(self...))`) and here is what I have so far...

```
class Starter:
    def __init__(self, startd, starterid, bidding):
        self.startd = startd
        self.starterid = starterid
        self.bidding = bidding
```

and now, I'm trying to implement a new class, Bidding, where each auction is identified by an auction identifier.

The class has the following features:

• It can be created via Bidding(bidding), **(bidding) is from class Starter btw**  for example,

```
bidtest = Auction('ewmzr')
```

creates an instance of Bidding with bidding identifier `'ewmzr'`.

• The method `beginbid(bidder_id)` reflects the action of the bidder with `bidder_id` placing a
bid on this auction. That is to say, if a is an Bidding instance, the call to `a.beginbid(starterid)` places a bid from a bidder with `starterid`.

• If a is a Bidding instance, then a.price is the current price of this bidding, and a.winner
is the current winner of this bidding. Before anyone places a bid, a.winner is, by convention,
None.

Here is what I have so far...

```
class Starter:
    def __init__(self, startd, starterid, bidding):
        self.startd = startd
        self.starterid = starterid
        self.bidding = bidding

c = Starter(1, '8dac2b', 'ewmzr')
class Bidding:
    def __init__(self,bidding):
        self.bidding = self.bidding
    def Beginbid(self,starterid):
        return starterid
```

However, this doesn't work at all. I think I'm not understanding the concept of classes ig. Can someone please help me solve this issue?

Comment: A couple of immediately obvious issues. You do `self.bidding = Starter(bidding)`, but the initialiser for your `Starter` class requires three arguments, not one. Your `Beginbid` method is missing the `self` parameter. Your description of the issue has code containing `Auction` as an example, but I suppose that was meant to be `Bidding`?

Comment: @Kemp yep, the obvious mistakes have been fixed. For the Starter(bidding) thing, I don't think I understand the concept of how can I extract only the bidding part of Starter

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want your bidding object to hold the id of the current highest bidder and that you want to give it an initial value of whoever started the bidding?

You could pass in the `Starter` object like this:

```
class Starter:
    def __init__(self, startd, starterid):
        self.startd = startd
        self.starterid = starterid

class Bidding:
    def __init__(self, starter):
        self.current_bidder = starter.starterid

c = Starter(1, '8dac2b', 'ewmzr')
b = Bidding(c)
```

It would probably work better to directly store a reference to the current bidder rather than their ID though:

```
class Starter:
    def __init__(self, startd, starterid):
        self.startd = startd
        self.starterid = starterid

class Bidding:
    def __init__(self, starter):
        self.current_bidder = starter

c = Starter(1, '8dac2b', 'ewmzr')
b = Bidding(c)
```

That way you don't need to be able to look up the object from its ID later.

If `begin_bid` is intended to update the current highest bidder then it simply looks like:

```
def begin_bid(self, bidder):
    self.current_bidder = bidder
```

The other methods would be variations on a theme after that, updating or fetching instance variables.

Does this help at all?

Comment: what about like the other factors? like the Beginbid()?? where and how should I put that??

Comment: I've made a quick update, but really it depends on how complex you're intending the logic to be. It's not completely clear from your description, but also I can't really just sit here and write all your code for you. Hopefully my answer has given you a base on which to add more of your code.